# Easy way to compute repeated residue calculus?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to evaluate an integral, which can be *in principle* computed exactly. For $a>0$ and $k_1, k_2 >0$, define $G(x) = (x+ia)^3$. The integral that I have is
$$I = \int_{\mathbb R^4} dy_1dy_2 dz_1 dz_2 e^{-ik_2 z_1} e^{-ik_1 z_2} e^{ik_2 y_1} e^{ik_1 y_2} \frac{G(z_2-y_1) G(z_1-y_2)}{G(z_2-z_1) G(z_2-y_2) G(z_1-y_1) G(y_1-y_2)}.$$
In principle, the evaluation of $I$ amounts to repeated residue calculation. More precisely, the sign of $e^{\pm i k x}$ dictates whether $x$ is contour-integrated either at upper or lower half plane, and each variables can be repeatedly integrated.

The complication is that $1/G$ has a pole of order 3. This makes the computation in practice hard, since we have to take 2nd derivative of to calculate the residue. Is there any other trick for evaluating $I$ (possibly not using contour integration)?

Comment: Use symbolic algebra software like Mathematica to compute residues. Mathematica has a Residue function.